# Variables printing as nan or inf instead of actual value

Tags: c++, class, variables, nan

I'm working on a program that calculates time based off of distance and speed and when I out put the final time it would take to get from point a to point b instead of getting 100 miles I'm getting either nan or inf depending on how my class is set up. Can someone help me out here?

Part of my class:

```
class Trip
{
private:
    string chicago, illinois, destCity, destState;
    double distance, time, rate;

public:
    Trip()
    {
        chicago = "Chicago";
        illinois = "Illinois";
        destCity = "";
        destState = "";
        distance = 0.0;
        time = 0.0;
        rate = 0.0;
    }

    Trip(string city, string state, double distance)
    {
        chicago = "Chicago";
        illinois = "Illinois";
        destCity = city;
        destState = state;
        distance = 0.0;
        time = 0.0;
        rate = 0.0;
    }
```

This is what a constructor would look like in my main method:

```
Trip atlanta("Atlanta", "Georgia", 587);
```

and then here are some mutator methods that could be part of the problem:

```
void Trip::setRate(double mph)
{
    mph = rate;
}

void Trip::calcTime()
{
    time = distance/rate;
}
```

now if i set up my class like so

```
this->city = "";
this->distance = 0.0;
```

when I use an accesor method to retrieve time, distance, etc is prints as "nan" but if I have my class set up like it

```
city = "";
distance = 0.0;
```

then I get "inf". 
When I debug the program the trip object shows  up with all the variables being 0 even after I pass values to the class members with the constructor. I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: Make sure `rate` is always a value other than zero

Comment: @DBR: Look at your `setRate()` function and ask what that assignment is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this function:

```
Trip(string city, string state, double distance)
{
    // ...
    distance = 0.0;
```

that last line sets *the function parameter* `distance`. Not the class member. The class member remains uninitalized , so you get garbage when you print it out sometimes.

To fix this you could write `this->distance = 0.0;`, or preferably use constructor initialization lists:

```
Trip(string city, string state, double distance)
    : chicago("Chicago")
    , distance(distance)
    , // etc.
 {
 }
```

And/or use different names for the parameters than you use for the class members.

In the initialization list, `distance(distance)` means that `this->distance` is initialized to the parameter `distance`, because the thing outside the parentheses has to be the name of a class member.

---

In C++11 you can set default values in the class definition, which avoids you having to repeat them in every constructor:

```
class Trip
{
private:
    string chicago, illinois, destCity, destState;
    double distance = 0.0;
    double time = 0.0;
    double rate = 0.0;
```

Note that there is no need to initialize `string`s to blank; they have a default constructor, so uninitialized `strings` are guaranteed to be empty strings, not garbage.

Comment: +1: Doesn't explain that the uninitialised values could be such that result in `nan` or `inf` on output after calculations, but close enough.

Comment: Right. I'm not too sure about the purpose of the class members `chicago` and `illinois` either!

Comment: I actually had it as this->distance = distance but forgot to change it back after toying with a few things, as @blastface pointed out my setRate method had the variables in the wrong spot which was actually causing a whole nother problem. Thanks for explaining this though, I changed up the format a little bit based off of yours, changed the parameter name and everything is running smooth!

Comment: Also the program calculates a distance to any city with the start location always being Chicago so that is what the chicago and illinois variables are for lol.

Comment: Calling them `startCity` and `startState` would make the most sense then :)